# How can I prove that this polynomial is irreducible?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I have a polynomial $y^4-10y^2+x^4-10x^2+20$ how can I prove that it is irreducible?

Wolfram says that it is. Also, I know that $p(x)+y$ is always irreducible, so $y':=y^4-10y^2$.

Comment: Where do you want to prove that the polynomial is irreducible ? Over integers,real number or complex number?

Comment: @TheDemonix_Hermit, over $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: not to mention, this one can be put in second degree. $(y^2)^2-10(y^2)+(x^2)^2-10(x^2)+20$